# DynamoDB's PaginatedList via REST

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk

For a web-application, I want to implement a paginated table. The DynamoDB "layout" is, that there are multiple items for a user, therefore I've chosen the `partition key=user` and the `sort key=created` (timestamp). The UI shall present the items in pages à 50 items from a total of a few 100 items.

The items are passed to the UI via REST-Api calls. I only want to `query` or `scan` a page of items, not the whole table. Pagination shall be possible forward and backward.

So far I've come up with the following, using the [`DynamoDBMapper`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html):

```java
/**
 * Returns the next page of items DEPENDENT OF THE USER. Note: This method internally uses
 * DynamoDB QUERY. Thus it requires "user" as a parameter. The "created" parameter is optional.
 * If provided, both parameters form the startKey for the pagination.
 * 
 * @param user - mandatory: The user for which to get the next page
 * @param created - optional: for providing a starting point
 * @param limit - the returned page will contain (up to) this number of items
 * @return
 */
public List<SampleItem> getNextPageForUser(final String user, final Long created, final int limit) {
    // To iterate DEPENDENT on the user we use QUERY. The DynamoDB QUERY operation
    // always require the partition key (=user).
    final SampleItem hashKeyObject = new SampleItem();
    hashKeyObject.setUser(user);

    // The created is optional. If provided, it references the starting point
    if (created == null) {
        final DynamoDBQueryExpression<SampleItem> pageExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<SampleItem>()//
                .withHashKeyValues(hashKeyObject)//
                .withScanIndexForward(true) //
                .withLimit(limit);
        return mapper.queryPage(SampleItem.class, pageExpression).getResults();
    } else {
        final Map<String, AttributeValue> startKey = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
        startKey.put(SampleItem.USER, new AttributeValue().withS(user));
        startKey.put(SampleItem.CREATED, new AttributeValue().withN(created.toString()));

        final DynamoDBQueryExpression<SampleItem> pageExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<SampleItem>()//
                .withHashKeyValues(hashKeyObject)//
                .withExclusiveStartKey(startKey)//
                .withScanIndexForward(true) //
                .withLimit(limit);
        return mapper.queryPage(SampleItem.class, pageExpression).getResults();
    }
}
```

The code for previous is similar, only that it uses `withScanIndexForward(false)`.

In my REST-Api controller I offer a single method:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/page/{user}/{created}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<SampleDTO> listQueriesForUserWithPagination(//
        @RequestParam(required = true) final String user,//
        @RequestParam(required = true) final Long created,//
        @RequestParam(required = false) final Integer n,//
        @RequestParam(required = false) final Boolean isBackward//
) {
    final int nrOfItems = n == null ? 100 : n;
    if (isBackward != null && isBackward.booleanValue()) {
        return item2dto(myRepo.getPrevQueriesForUser(user, created, nrOfItems));
    } else {
        return item2dto(myRepo.getNextQueriesForUser(user, created, nrOfItems));
    }
}
```

I wonder if I am re-inventing the wheel with this approach.

Would it be possible to pass the DynamoDB's `PaginatedQueryList` or `PaginatedScanList` to the UI via REST, so that if the javascript pagination accesses the items, that then they are loaded lazily.
From working with other DBs I have never transferred DB entry objects, which is why my code-snippet re-packs the data (`item2dto`).

In addition, the pagination with DynamoDB appears a bit strange: So far I've seen no possibility to provide the UI with a total count of items. So the UI only has buttons for "next page" and "previous page", without actually knowing how many pages will follow. Directly jumping to page 5 is therefore not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Console does not load all your data at once to conserve on read capacity. When you get a Scan/Query page, you only get information about how to get the next page, so that is why the console is not able to show you a-priory how many pages of data it can show. Depending on your schema, you may be able to support random page access in your application. This is done by deciding a-priori how large pages will be and second encoding something like a page number in the partition key. Please see [this AWS Forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=620485&#620485) for details.